# Get row count from two sql queries that have been unioned together

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a two SQL Queries

- Both queries contain multiple joins.
- Both queries have the same column names.

What I did was:

- `Query1 UNION Query2` (Which is working correctly)

**[PROBLEM]**

I am trying to get the row count of the combined queries.

As of now, I am trying to do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (QUERY1)
UNION
(QUERY2) A
```

My problem is both contain the same column aliases which results in an error since SQL doesn't accept duplicate columns.

Is there any way to count the rows from this query?

Comment: SELECT COUNT ( * )
FROM
( QUERY1 UNION QUERY2
) D

Comment: Trust you know that UNION potentially removes rows (to remove duplicated rows) and hence you may need UNION ALL (which does not remove rows)

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? `sql-server` or `mysql` ?

Comment: opps. sorry, I tag the wrong key..
I am using MySQL

Comment: would you please share your current queries?